# Reusing a mixed Channel with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Surely I'm missing a fundamental here with NAudio. I am trying to **play the same sound twice** and cannot. What's going on?

```
var path = @"\Rim Shot 2.wav";
var path2 = @"\Rim Shot 4.wav";

var mStream1 = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
var mStream2 = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path2));

var stream1 = (new WaveFileReader(mStream1)).ToStandardWaveStream();
var stream2 = (new WaveFileReader(mStream2)).ToStandardWaveStream();

stream1.WaveFormat.Dump();
stream2.WaveFormat.Dump();

var channel1 = new SampleChannel(stream1);
var channel2 = new SampleChannel(stream2);

var format = stream1.WaveFormat;
format = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(format.SampleRate, format.Channels);
var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(format);
mixer.ReadFully = true;

try
{
    output.Init(mixer);
    output.Play();

    mixer.AddMixerInput(channel1);
    Task.Delay(10).Wait();

    mixer.AddMixerInput(channel2);
    Task.Delay(10).Wait();

    mixer.AddMixerInput(channel1);
    Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.Dump();
}
finally
{
    if(mStream1 != null) mStream1.Dispose();
    if(mStream2 != null) mStream2.Dispose();

    if(stream1 != null) stream1.Dispose();
    if(stream2 != null) stream2.Dispose();
}
```

where `ToStandardWaveStream()` is my extension method:

```
public static WaveStream ToStandardWaveStream(this WaveStream stream)
{
    if(stream == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("The expected Wave Stream is not here.");

    var encoding = stream.WaveFormat.Encoding;
    var isNotPcmFormat = (encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm);
    var isNotIeeeFloatFormat = (encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat);

    Func<WaveStream> convert = () =>
    {
        stream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(stream);
        stream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(stream);
        return stream;
    };

    return (isNotPcmFormat && isNotIeeeFloatFormat) ? convert() : stream;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the same stream as an input to the mixer twice. You need to create a second, brand new stream reading from the same WAV file to add. This second stream will be at the beginning. For efficiency, in a drum machine, I'd cache the sound data (as you are doing), but you'd still need to create new WaveFileReaders (or RawSourceStreams), so they start from the beginning

For an example of this in action, look at the NAudio source code for the [WPF Drum machine demo](http://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioWpfDemo/DrumMachineDemo/DrumPatternSampleProvider.cs).

Comment: i took your Twitter advice from yesterday and got [this](https://gist.github.com/BryanWilhite/8c7ad3d154aa0c5d07dc) working. Do take a careful look at my `NAudioCore.MixAsync()` overloads. Streams _are_ being reused but as you pointed out they have to IO-Seek reset.

Comment: that's fine if you definitely know the originals stopped playing before re-queuing them, or mixer will be attempting to read twice from the same stream

Comment: is there any penalty for calling ‘remove mixer input’ for a channel previously removed form the mixer (eager removal)?